# dispatch_async without effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have multiple buttons and I want for each button to have an image from an url.
What I was trying to do and it's not working ( the buttons are without image ). If I'm trying to do the same thing without dispatch it's working but it's taking time. Where am I wrong?

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Add code here to do background processing
    NSString *imageURL = pictureUrl[i];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [bt setBackgroundImage:imageView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    });
});
```

Comment: How did you initialized the bt ?

Comment: @MidhunMP :  UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Answer (score 3):

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     // Add code here to do background processing
     NSString *imageURL = pictureUrl[i];
     NSData *imageData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
     UIImage *image     = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
          [bt setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     });
});
```

You do everything in background and then do nothing on the main thread. Instead download the data in background and work with UI on the main thread. Also no need to have the imageView

Comment: @Georgiana well, this code must work. Probably you've got an error somewhere else

Comment: @Georgiana that's completely different question. You need to figure out why it is nil

Comment: @Rob the URL is valid and there is not problem with networking connection

Comment: @Georgiana: If possible, can you share the image url ?

Comment: @Rob  (lldb) po pictureUrl[0]
http: //www.radioszene.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/917xfm.png     the space between : and // doesnt exist. I put it there to see that the prefix is on url

Comment: @Georgiana
You have a space http: //www.!!!!!!That's why it doesn't work.
Try to copy your url with space and put it to your browser. It wouldn't work.

Comment: @СергейОлейнич there is no space . I put it there for showing you that the url has the preffix.

Comment: @Georgiana
Please can you make 
NSString *imageURL = pictureUrl[i];
**NSLog(@"%@", imageURL)**
and show us the result.

Comment: @СергейОлейнич 2015-01-09 15:31:33.203 TV[2787:810120] Image URL : http://www.radioszene.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/917xfm.png

Comment: @Georgiana just make NSLog and post it here

Comment: @Georgiana is it from NSLog?

Comment: @Georgiana put it in your question. As a comment in code

Comment: @Georgiana
Try to do this:
NSString *imageURL = @"http:/www.radioszene.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/917xfm.png"; instead of your imageURL.

Comment: @Georgiana
I wrote this code and it work well. http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qI1e.png

Answer (score 2):

1. You report that `imageData` is `nil`:

   ```
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]
   ```

   If that's the case, you should first check to see if the `NSURL` object is `nil` or not:

   ```
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
   NSLog(@"URL = %@", URL);
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
   ```

   The URL a might look OK, but only by looking at the `NSURL` value will you confirm this.
2. If, as you seem to be insisting, the URL is fine (and you've confirmed the `NSURL` is not `nil`), but the `NSData` is still coming up `nil`, then you should use a different retrieval mechanism, one that returns an `NSError` explaining why it failed. For example you could replace this `dispatch_async` to he background with a call to `sendAsynchronousRequest` and if the `NSData` was `nil`, then look at the `NSError` object.
3. Presumably needless to say at this point, but make sure that all of the updates of UI controls (such as the image view) are dispatched back to the main queue.